# Find $a_n$ for the fourier series $\cos(3x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\cos(2n+1)x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Given $\cos(3x) = u(x,0)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\cos(2n+1)x,\quad\forall 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$

Hello !
So I have been a solving a PDE question and this is the final step, where I have applied initial condition to the general solution and I am face to face with the Fourier series. I have to find the the value of term $a_n.$ The book gives the answer that $a_1=1$ and $a_n=0,\quad\forall n = 0,2,3,4,5\ldots$

Following is my calculations so far :

$\cos(3x) =a_0\cos(x)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos(2n+1)x$

Since the series is Fourier cosine with $p=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $a_0, a_n$ are given by :

$a_0=\frac{1}{p}\int_{0}^{p} \cos(3x){\rm d}x$

$a_n=\frac{2}{p}\int_{0}^{p} \cos(2n+1)\cos(3x){\rm d}x$

I am solving both but answer for $a_0=-\frac{2}{3}\pi$ and I didn't solve for $a_n$ since $a_0$ is not equal to zero required as per answer in the book.
Can any one guide me where I am making the mistake ?

Comment: Your $a_0$ is wrong. Put n=0 in your $a_n$. Also, why calculate anything, you can see the solution.

Comment: I can see the solution. But I want to solve via proper mathematical method to arrive at it, which I am failing at. Kindly guide or hint me

Comment: $a_n$ gives all of the coefficients. The writer's $a_0$ is what you might call $a_1$. The writer has re-ordered the original fourier sum  to include only odd n terms as the even terms (including $a_0$) are zero.

Comment: No writer has included all terms odd and even & wrote $a_n=0$ for all $n=0,2,3,4,5...$ and $a_1=1$

Comment: Sorry, but by pure inspection of the RHS, it is indeed **evident** that $a_1=0$ and all other coefficients are $0$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Werner's identities
$$ \begin{split}
2\cos (\alpha) \cos (\beta)&=\cos (\alpha-\beta)+\cos (\alpha+\beta),\\
2\sin (\alpha) \cos (\beta)&=\sin (\alpha-\beta)+\sin (\alpha+\beta),
\end{split}$$
and the related prosthaphaeresis formulae
$$\sin(\alpha\pm\beta)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)\pm\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha),  $$
we find
$$\begin{split}
\frac 4 \pi \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(3x)\cos(kx)dx&= \frac 2 {\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos((3-k)x)dx+\frac 1 \pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos((3+k)x)dx \\
&=\frac 2 {\pi} \left[\frac 1 {k-3}\int_0^{\pi(k-3)/2}\cos(u)du+\frac 1{k+3}\int_0^{\pi(k+3)/2}\cos(u)du \right]\\
&=\frac 2 {\pi} \left[\frac {1} {k-3} \sin \left(\frac{\pi(k-3)}{2} \right)+\frac {1} {k+3} \sin \left(\frac{\pi(k+3)}{2} \right)\right]\\
&= \frac{2}{\pi} \left[\frac{2k \sin(k\pi/2)\cos(3\pi/2) - 6\sin(3\pi/2)\cos(k\pi/2)}{k^2-9} \right]\\
&= \frac{12}\pi \frac{1}{k^2-9} \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2} \right).
\end{split}$$
Your book's notation is retrieved by setting $k=(2n+1)$; thus, the case $n=0$ corresponds to $k=1$, where the integral evaluates to $12/\pi \cdot \cos(\pi/2)/(-8) = 0$.

Observe that the singularity at $k=3$ is removable: by continuity, you can insert the value
$$\lim_{k\to 3} \frac{12}{\pi} \frac{1}{k^2-9} \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2} \right) = 1. $$
This corresponds to the fact that
$$\frac 4 \pi \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2(3x) dx = 1. $$

Comment: The last expression is not equal to zero. This is not required answer

Comment: Plug in $k=(2n+1)$ and evaluate the cosine when $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Here $p=\pi/2$ but you have chosen $p=\pi$. Can you explain why?

Comment: Also after substituting for $k=2n+1$ doesn't yield $a_1=1$. It yields $0$ for all natural numbers

Comment: @Ameer This is $0$ for all natural numbers $n$ *except* $n = 1$, where $k = 3$ and $k^2 - 9 = 0$.

Comment: @Ameer I've expanded my answer slightly. Hope this helps